# How to use REST API for Azure blob storage,with Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure, i am trying to use REST API for uploading image to Azure blob but unable to find any referance/material which explains the process using Java, i found examples using c# but i want to implement functionality using Java.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you're asking about using the REST API for blobs (which is fully documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135733.aspx)). However: Given that there's a Java SDK built atop that REST API, you should really look at that unless there's some specific functionality you need that's not implemented in the SDK. And even in that case, you're welcome to update the SDK and submit your changes back to the Azure team, as the SDK source is in [github](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java).

Here's [documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/blob-storage/) on using the Java SDK for working with blobs, and here are the [download links](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/) for the language-specific SDKs including Java.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i am looking to establish a secure chennal and upload image to blob, so i am trying to write http client which will help me call rest based services of Azure, but i am unable to code it properly as i have no referance how to code it. the documentation link you put in your answer, i have already gone through it.

Comment: what i am trying to create request headers for creating a blob and trying to request, as of now what i received was 403 from server, still looking into the same. i am looking for implementation referance which may guide me to code properly, i am making some mistake and unable to understand what..:(

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure SDK for Java calls the REST API under the hood, why not using Java SDK? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#UploadBlob

Answer (score -1):

@VJD I have written some guidance docs to using the Java API, with sample Java code. This ought to be published on MSDN in the next day or so.  I will post a link here once it goes live. Here are the links to the entire content.

[Controlling Access to Windows Azure Blob Containers with Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246928.aspx)

[Controlling Access to Windows Azure Queues with Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246927.aspx)

[Controlling Access to Windows Azure Tables with Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246929.aspx)

You can control access to blob containers in your storage account in several ways, but the use of stored access policy may be the most flexible.  This enables you to give temporary access to clients, without revealing your secret storage account key, and enables you to cancel, extend, or update the type of access without having to redistribute basic SAS strings.

For example, your application can generate a stored access policy signature for a container using Java code similar to the following.

```
public class PolicySAS
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, 
     URISyntaxException, StorageException 
  {
  Account creds = new Account();     //Account key required to create SAS           
  final String storageConnectionString = creds.getstorageconnectionstring();
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
     CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
  CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
  CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("container1");
  container.createIfNotExist();
  SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
  GregorianCalendar calendar = 
     new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  calendar.setTime(new Date());
  policy.setSharedAccessStartTime(calendar.getTime()); //Immediately applicable
  calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 3); //Applicable time-span is 3 hours
  policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(calendar.getTime());           
  policy.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ, 
     SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.DELETE, 
     SharedAccessBlobPermissions.LIST));
  BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
  //Private container with no access for anonymous users
  containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.OFF);
  //Name the shared access policy: heath
  containerPermissions.getSharedAccessPolicies().put("heath", policy);
  container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);
  //Generate the policy SAS string for heath access
  String sas = container.generateSharedAccessSignature(
     new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(),"heath");           
  System.out.println("The stored access policy signature:");
  System.out.println(sas);
  }         
}
```

A client can use a class similar to this to upload a blob with metadata.

```
public class SASblober 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, 
      FileNotFoundException, StorageException, IOException 
   {                        
   //This does not reveal the secret storage account key
   URI baseuri = new URI("http://grassy.blob.core.windows.net");
   CloudBlobClient blobclient = new CloudBlobClient(baseuri);
   MyUploadBlob("container1",
     "sr=c&sv=2012-02-12&sig=nnPn5P5nnPPnn5Pnn5PPnPPPnPPP5PPPPPP%5PPnn5PPn%55&si=heath",
      blobclient);          
   }

   public static void MyUploadBlob(String containerName, String containerSAS, 
      CloudBlobClient blobClient) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, 
      FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {    
   //Uploads a local file to blob-container in cloud
   String blobName = "image3.jpg";  
   String localFileName = "c:\\myimages\\image3.jpg";  
   URI uri = new URI(blobClient.getEndpoint().toString() + "/" +
     containerName + "/" + 
     blobName + 
     "?" + 
     containerSAS);
   CloudBlockBlob sasBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(uri, blobClient);
   HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();    
   user.put("firstname", "Joe");
   user.put("lastname", "Brown" );
   user.put("age", "28");
   user.put("presenter", "no");  
   sasBlob.setMetadata(user);
   File fileReference = new File(localFileName);
   sasBlob.upload(new FileInputStream(fileReference), fileReference.length());
   System.out.println("The blob: " + blobName + " has been uploaded to:");
   System.out.println(uri);
   }
}
```

A client can use a class similar to this to read a blob.

```
public class SASread 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, 
      FileNotFoundException, StorageException, IOException 
   {                        
   URI baseuri = new URI("http://grassy.blob.core.windows.net");
   CloudBlobClient blobclient = new CloudBlobClient(baseuri);
   MyDownloadBlob("container1",
     "sr=c&sv=2012-02-12&sig=nnPn5P5nnPPnn5Pnn5PPnPPPnPPP5PPPPPP%5PPnn5PPn%55&si=heath",
       blobclient);         
    }

   public static void MyDownloadBlob(String containerName, String containerSAS, 
      CloudBlobClient blobClient) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, 
      FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {
   //   Downloads blob in cloud to local file
   String blobName = "image3.jpg";  
   String localFileName = "c:\\myoutputimages\\image3.jpg";  
   URI uri = new URI(blobClient.getEndpoint().toString() + "/" + containerName 
      + "/" + blobName + "?" + containerSAS);   
   CloudBlockBlob sasBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(uri, blobClient);    
   File fileTarget = new File(localFileName); 
   sasBlob.download(new FileOutputStream(fileTarget));   
   HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();    
   user = sasBlob.getMetadata();    
   String name = (user.get("firstname") + " " + user.get("lastname"));
   String age = ("age: " + user.get("age"));
   String present = ("Presenting talk? " + user.get("presenter"));
   System.out.println(name);
   System.out.println(age);
   System.out.println(present);
   System.out.println("The blob at:\n"  + uri 
      + "\nwas downloaded from the cloud to local file:\n" + localFileName);    
   }
}
```

Comment: hay mark i really appreciate your help, but this is what is using API functions provided by Azure, what i am looking for is to directly call rest service of Azure to upload image/file as a blob.

Comment: You are welcome. As David Makogon mentioned however the recommended method is to use the API if that is possible. Is there something not available in the SDK that you feel you need?

Comment: No nothing is missing in API, correct me if l am wrong but what l think and l also came across an article, where l read, that over the internet using API will expose functions like uploadBlob and similar, so l want to communicate over secure channel being on the safer side.

Comment: You can control access to blob containers, queues, and tables using public access, shared access signatures, and stored access policy - as described in the articles I linked to above. You should use https to send the sas urls to clients. Communication is secure and you control access to your Azure storage resources.